# Seaborn's lineplot incorrectly shows a part of xticks. How to fix it?

Tags: python, seaborn, subplot

This is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,3, figsize=(16,6), sharex=True)

col = df.columns
index = 0

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(3):
        sns.lineplot(x=df.index, y=df[col[index]], ax=ax[i][j])
        ax[i][j].set_xticklabels(df.index, rotation=45, ha='right')
        index = index + 1

plt.tight_layout()
```

However, I get the following output. Only a few days of January are shown as xticks whereas the range is from January 1 to April 28 in my dataframe. Also, see that the xticks are timestamps, even though in the dataframe only dates are shown. I want only dates in xticks. How to fix them?

[image]

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the line `ax[i][j].set_xticklabels(df.index, rotation=45, ha='right')`. You are replacing the handful of ticks that were automatically selected by matplotlib with the first few values of your date index.

Instead, I would use `plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')` to modify the rotation of the existing labels.

Note that you have set `sharex=True`, so you don't have to do this operation on all the axes, just on one of them is enough to be applied globally

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(3):
        sns.lineplot(x=df.index, y=df[col[index]], ax=ax[i][j])
        index = index + 1

plt.setp(ax[0,0].get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the new problem is all dates are tight despite the plt.tight_layout()! Rotation does not work! Any idea?

Comment: Would you mind looking at this problem of mine as well? I was really waiting for an answer. Much thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61495419/how-to-add-legends-labels-and-fix-tight-layout-in-a-subplot-with-multiple-plot